# Task with Authenticated Website

Tags: customer-portal, tasks

Can I run following code after login as customer portal user in apex controller?

```
task.WhatId = Object.id;
task.WhoId = Object.Editor__c;
task.Subject = 'Other';
task.priority= Object.Priority__c;
task.status = 'Not Started';
task.description = 'New  Work';
insert task;
```

I am getting error "Currently DML is not allowed". I want to create a task for customer portal user. Is that possible? I don't want show it to any user. I will just use it to send notification email. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well seems like you are doing DML from either **Constructor** or **Getter** method. Please try to do the same from **action** attribute of the **page** by calling a method

Comment: I am calling an action method from VF page and action method calls this code. Please note context user is customer portal user.

Answer (score 2):

There's a blog post about this from Wes Nolte that even contains a short poem:

http://th3silverlining.com/2009/11/23/dml-currently-not-allowed/

This covers all of the scenarios and solutions for each of them.